# Mazda tech says crank sensor in distributor

Tags: mazda, crank-position-sensor

Apparently my crank sensor is in the distributor on my Mazda Demio.  The engine type is Mazda B3E, and the distributor is B5B4 T2T60572 ...  I can’t find it anywhere else but how is this possible ? Many thanks :)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

Because the distributor is driven directly from the crankshaft at half-speed.

This means the sensor is picking up a "slower" signal and either way it gives the ecu the information needed.

Other engines use a sensor based on the flywheel rotation and the signal needs to be divided by 2, done in the ecu.

Comment: thanks mike, is it less or more likely to go wrong than a crank shaft located one? thanks again, and seeing as they sell one, do we dismantle the distributor to fit a new one?